# SQL Server throws timeout when I execute a stored procedure through an application, but not when I execute it in the Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I have a stored procedure that is something like this:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure]
 @period varchar(7),
 @pgSize int,
 @pg int,
 @sort varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @order varchar(100)
    DECLARE @where varchar(100)

    CREATE TABLE #temp (
        fieldOne varchar(7),
        fieldTwo varchar(7),
        fieldThree int,
        fieldFour varchar(7)
    )   

    If exists(select 1 from tableA Where date = @period)
    Begin
        INSERT INTO #temp
        SELECT DISTINCT a.fieldOne, b.fieldTwo, td.fieldThree, b.fieldFour
        FROM tableA a
        LEFT JOIN docType td ON td.code = a.docType
        INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.code = b.code
        AND b.state= 'A'
        AND a.date = convert(int, @period);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #temp
        SELECT DISTINCT a.fieldOne, b.fieldTwo, td.fieldThree, b.fieldFour
        FROM tableAHistoric a
        LEFT JOIN docType td ON td.code = a.docType
        INNER JOIN tableBHistoric b ON a.code = b.code
        AND b.state= 'A'
        AND a.date = convert(int, @period);
    END

    -- Eliminate registers such that there is another register with the same fieldOne but different fieldTwo, and keep the one that has smaller fieldThree or,
    -- in case they are equal, keep the one with smallest fieldFour
    DELETE t1
    FROM #temp t1
    INNER JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.fieldOne = t2.fieldOne AND t1.fieldTwo <> t2.fieldTwo
    WHERE t1.fieldThree > t2.fieldThree OR (t1.fieldThree = t2.fieldThree AND t1.fieldFour > t2.fieldFour)

    SET @order = ' order by ' + CASE LEFT(@sort, 1) WHEN '-' THEN SUBSTRING(@sort, 2, LEN(@sort) - 1) + ' desc' ELSE @sort END 

    IF @pg = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @exec = CONCAT(
                'select * from #temp ', 
                @order, 
                ' offset (@pg-1) * @pgSize rows  fetch next @pgSize rows only '
                )

        EXEC sp_executesql @exec, N'@pg int, @pgSize int', @pg = @pg, @pgSize = @pgSize
        SELECT rows = COUNT(*) FROM #temp
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @exec = CONCAT(
                'select * from #temp ', 
                @order, 
                ' offset (@pg-1) * @pgSize rows  fetch next @pgSize rows only '
                )
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @exec, N'@pg int, @pgSize int', @pg = @pg, @pgSize = @pgSize
    END
```

If I query this from SQL Server Management Studio with the following parameters:

```
EXEC myStoredProcedure '201603', 10, 1, 'fieldOne'
```

It returns within a second.

If I hardcode '201603' in the variable `@period` and execute the stored procedure from my Node.js application, it returns within a second as well.

However, if I pass that parameter while executing the stored procedure through the Node.js application, I get a timeout. I've registered that the stored procedure either never gets to execute the INSERT or never finishes before a timeout. The timeout is set in 15 seconds, and I've set it to 2 minutes to test, but the results are the same: timeout. What's funny is that it happens only for that value: '201603'. The result should return 889 registers. I've tested it with other values that return 200 results, and they have no problem.

For reference, the field `date` is an integer. But even if I convert the parameter `@period` in the `WHERE` clause, nothing changes.

What could be the problem? What should I look into?

Thanks.

Comment: Nowhere in your proc is `@period` being used as a `VARCHAR`, so why is it declared as one?  If you only use it as an `INT`, you should declare it as an `INT`.

Comment: @Siyual: though that's a good point, I've found it doesn't make any difference passing `@period` as an `INT` to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a cached execution plan.

Try adding "OPTION (RECOMPILE)" at the bottom of your SP